# Android Shared Preference Restarting App

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

So I was following tutorial and everything was fine and right until I ran the app and encountered this problem. Everytime I restarted my app my activity will just go back to LoginActivity instead of MainActivity. Here's my code

**Session Manager**

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "users";

private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
//userID and userName
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
// public static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";

//Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    this.pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    this.editor = pref.edit();
    this.editor.commit();
    this.editor.clear();
}

public void createLoginSession(String username) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    editor.commit();
    // editor.putString(KEY_USERID, userID);
}

public void checkLogin() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, SplashScreen.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this._context.startActivity(i);
    }
}


public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));
    return user;
}

public void logoutUser() {
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, SplashScreen.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
```

**Login Activity**

```
TextView register_link;
Button btnLogin;
EditText eTxtUsername, eTxtPassword;
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    //
    register_link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_register_link);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    eTxtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTxt_username);
    eTxtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTxt_password);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    //
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Login status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    register_link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String username_ = eTxtUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password_ = eTxtPassword.getText().toString();

            if (isEmptyFields(username_, password_)) {
                builder.setMessage("Please provide all fields")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            final boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                final String userid_ = String.valueOf(jsonResponse.getInt("userid"));

                                session.createLoginSession(username_);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("userId", userid_);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username_, password_, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

static boolean isEmptyFields(String n1, String pw1) {
    final boolean result;

    if (n1.isEmpty() || pw1.isEmpty())
        result = true;
    else
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
private Drawer result = null;
private String userid;
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final Button btn_showlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_showlist);
    session = new SessionManager(this);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Login status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    session.checkLogin();
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // userid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
    String username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);

    //create drawer
    new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
    CreateDrawer(CreateAccountDrawer(), toolbar);

    btn_showlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    result.deselect();
}

//CREATE DRAWER
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

private AccountHeader CreateAccountDrawer() {

    AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header1)
            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("New User").withIcon(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.profile))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

    return headerResult;

}

private void CreateDrawer(AccountHeader header, Toolbar toolbar) {

    PrimaryDrawerItem p_item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withSetSelected(true).withIdentifier(1)
            .withName(R.string.map).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_map);
    PrimaryDrawerItem p_item2 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2)
            .withName(R.string.analyze_soil).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bullseye);
    PrimaryDrawerItem p_item3 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3)
            .withName(R.string.drawer_item_statistic).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_line_chart);
    //
    SecondaryDrawerItem s_item1 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4)
            .withName(R.string.drawer_item_app_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog);
    SecondaryDrawerItem s_item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5)
            .withName(R.string.drawer_item_account_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog);
    SecondaryDrawerItem s_item3 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(6)
            .withName(R.string.logout).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_out);

    //Create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` result object
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withAccountHeader(header)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    p_item2,
                    p_item1,
                    p_item3,
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    s_item1,
                    s_item2,
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    s_item3
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                    int clickedID = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                    Intent i;
                    switch (clickedID) {
                        case 1:
                            drawerItem.withSetSelected(false);
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            drawerItem.withSetSelected(false);
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnalyzeSoilActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            drawerItem.withSetSelected(false);
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StatisticActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            drawerItem.withSetSelected(false);
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettingActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            drawerItem.withSetSelected(false);
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountSettingActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            session.logoutUser();
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();
}
```

Comment: remove `this.editor.clear();` from constructor. it may looper

Comment: Start over and read this again. There is no clear or commit  in the constructor.  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: Already removed this.editor.clear(); and starting it over again. still the same problem. I also tried to look for the xml file for sharedpreferences no luck. stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you seems like you are creating your session instance on every activity. Try to create  singleton class of shared preference instead . and here when you are invoking the constructor

```
//Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    this.pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    this.editor = pref.edit();
    this.editor.commit();
    this.editor.clear();
}
```

the editor.clear() is called which is clearing you preferences when you reach main activity

Comment: still not working bro. I used a toast to show what's the status of login and it shows true but everytime I restarted the app it will just go back to Login Activity.

Comment: did you you a singleton class for shared preferences ?

Comment: You could [edit] your answer instead of providing another

Answer (score 0):

you must change your SessionManager constructor like below:

```
public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    this.pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    this.editor = pref.edit();
    this.editor.commit();
}
```

you called clear method on editor, so every time you run MainActivity,session manager will first read shared pref values and then you clear them. it's like your are clearing values and then you want data from it!

Comment: still not working bro. I used a toast to show what's the status of login and it shows true but everytime I restarted the app it will just go back to Login Activity.

Answer (score 0):

public class MyPreferences implements AppConstants, VCardStorage {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyPreferences";
private static final String APP_PREFS = "my_prefs";

private static MyPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private Editor mEditor;
private Context mContext;


private MyPreferences(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
}

public static MyPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mPreferences == null) {
        mPreferences = new MyPreferences(context);
    }
    return mPreferences;
}

public void removeKey(String key) {
    mEditor.remove(key).apply();
}

public void clear() {
    mEditor.clear().commit();
    ciaoPreferences = null;
}

public AppState getAppState() {
    String state = mPreferences.getString(PREFS_APP_STATE, AppState.INSTALLED.name());
    return AppState.valueOf(state);
}

public void setAppState(AppState state) {
    mEditor.putString(PREFS_APP_STATE, state.name()).apply();
}
```

Comment: try using this  singleton class .It works and  in my app i have maintained app states using enum values as  i am having 2-3 states in my application

Comment: The singleton (while better), isn't the solution. Check the code again after reading my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Everytime I restarted my app my activity will just go back to LoginActivity instead of MainActivity

Probably because LoginActivity (or SplashActivity) is the main  activity set in the manifest.

There's no code in onCreate that starts the MainActivity outside of the login activity button click. Implementing SharedPreferences won't just do that for you.

```
// top of onCreate 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
boolean loggedIn = session.isLoggedIn()
Toast.makeText(this, "Login status: "  + loggedIn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (loggedIn) {
    // start MainActivity
    finish(); // don't need this activity 
} else {
    // load LoginActivity 
}
```

---

Also remove from the constructor

```
this.editor.clear();
```

Comment: Yes the Splash Activity in manifest was set as my Launcher. Already tried to remove the this.editor.clear(); still have the problem

Comment: You didn't read the rest of the post. Where's the startActivity when you are logged in??

Comment: It's in the Main Activity.